# Copy cell values over to new worksheet but not the formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy over the cell values and contents over to a new, locked worksheet, but currently the code is bringing over the original worksheet's formatting. Currently the code I am using is:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Sheets("LTL Quote Form").Range("A1:L33").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

And I've even tried:

```
Sub Copy()

    Sheets("LTL Quote Form").Range("A5:L11").Copy

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:L11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

But neither of them are working. Any suggestions on how to copy over the cell values, but not the formatting?

Comment: Set ranges to each other instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example you posted will paste values, not formatting. You could also use:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:L33").Value2 = Sheets("LTL Quote Form").Range("A1:L33").Value2

End Sub
```